# How to convert WKT polygons to kml file using python?

Tags: python, convert, kml, well-known-text

I have a set of data id with polygons.
I want to convert the dataframe to kml file using python.
an example of the data is like so

```
rtid_key,geometry 
40314,POLYGON ((106.79137124474583 -6.164311707677381, 106.79137168485848 -6.16430071122585, 106.79137307520114 -6.16426596840807, 106.79137669615109 -6.164175503602752, 106.79137834323835 -6.164134349202208, 106.79138197275725 -6.1640308206050936, 106.79144969286747 -6.164032648215645, 106.79160213326787 -6.1640326304020565, 106.7916574729182 -6.164032623404948, 106.79171577040032 -6.164032616404823, 106.7917598379467 -6.164032612027056, 106.79175983277797 -6.163986925050508, 106.79187559206979 -6.163980187552802, 106.79197024139476 -6.163974679275572, 106.79198748542723 -6.163973676417985, 106.79207757691844 -6.163968432099229, 106.79209639441683 -6.163967337145296, 106.792179616653 -6.163962492954774, 106.79221129829457 -6.163960648566995, 106.79227404736785 -6.163956997114851, 106.79230780468794 -6.163955032717686, 106.79238696678276 -6.163950424580226, 106.7924023753964 -6.163949528247264, 106.79247742587496 -6.1639451599717905, 106.79250389483283 -6.163943619726531, 106.79252305241418 -6.163941836428923, 106.7925857507736 -6.163936000585846, 106.79264003810863 -6.16393094712088, 106.79268430862815 -6.163926827012279, 106.79277631593811 -6.163918262275172, 106.79279571736541 -6.16391645644745, 106.79281698261964 -6.163914396601332, 106.79283631257286 -6.164204182693336, 106.79292392545213 -6.164197985405297, 106.79308273432663 -6.164186749133235, 106.79328953556394 -6.164172118853521, 106.79336420643305 -6.164164476744211, 106.79340623673474 -6.164160175133798, 106.79340899142281 -6.164451999776032, 106.79306733742756 -6.164466566661924, 106.79289300016804 -6.164473999722819, 106.7928463535784 -6.164480000434269, 106.7919543625494 -6.164594751249555, 106.79172700003795 -6.1646240004473105, 106.79172736933722 -6.16431062176255, 106.79137124474583 -6.164311707677381))
```

I am stuck at

```
import simplekml
from google.colab import files
import csv

kml=simplekml.Kml()
df = csv.reader(open('gp.csv','r'))
for row in df:
  kml.newpoint(name=row[0], coords=[(row[1])])
kml.save('kmlfile.kml')
```

However the polygon are not read properly, is there a formating that must be done? Because I tried loading the KML file and it does not load as it must in google my map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, using some modern packages.

```
import fiona
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd 
from shapely import wkt

# Enable KML support
fiona.supported_drivers['KML'] = 'rw'

df = pd.read_csv('./gp.csv')

# convert wkt to geometries
geoms = [wkt.loads(shape_text) for shape_text in df.geometry.tolist()]

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df[['rtid_key']], geometry = gpd.GeoSeries(geoms, crs='EPSG:4326'))

gdf.to_file('kmlfile.kml', driver='KML')
```

Comment: KML isn't EPSG:4326, KML is http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/OGC/0/LonLat84_5773

Comment: geom_wkt needs to be change with shape_text. it's working fine